# Exceeding number of entries on Schengen National visa (type D)

Tags: visa, schengen, portugal

I’m currently in the process of moving to Portugal with a D visa with 120 days validity and two entries.

The wait time to get a residence permit with my visa may take up to 6-8 months, and so there’s high likelihood I would need to exit and enter more than twice. I am, however, from a country with Schengen Visa free travel, so I was wondering if the number of entries would even affect my ability to re-enter?

Edit: to make it clear the purpose of this visa is to allow me to enter Portugal and apply for a residence permit, which at the moment has a long wait time

Comment: This SE:Travel thread is similar: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141115/arriving-in-france-before-the-start-of-a-student-visa-can-i-go-to-the-uk-and-co

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my situation would revolve entries Portugal/Schengen during the period of the visa, rather than outside of it. The purpose of D visa is to exchange for a residence permit, which has a long wait in the case of PT.

Comment: Good question. It doesn't _seem_ to make a lot of sense to issue a D visa to a visa-free national with less than multiple entries ...

Comment: If the wait time is 6 to 8 months and they only gave you 120 days (4 months), then they clearly don't want you to apply for a residence permit, IMHO.

Comment: Quite the norm I’m afraid. The visa allows me to get an appointment, which essentially ‘extends’ the visa until my appointment (but only valid for Portugal). Was/is a common practice in Italy as well from my experience

Comment: @jcaron that conclusion seems to impute a greater degree of logical sense to the bureaucracy than I suppose is actually warranted.

Answer (score 1):

The D-Visa being issue is to travel to and apply for the residence permit.

Once applied, a **temporary** residence permit will be issued for the expected time needed until the **final** residence permit is issued.

Since D-Visas are country specific, this may not be true for all countries but for France and Germany it is.

---

I have found the [Portuguese SEF](https://imigrante.sef.pt/en/novo-regulamento/) site that explains some new regulations about the residence permit process.

Up to now, after the initial arrival with the issued D-Visa, you are required to make an appointment with the SEF localy.

This appointment can now be done beforehand when the date of arrival is known.

> The Immigration and Borders Service, in situations where it is informed of the travel date, will provide, in the several favorable opinions concerning residence visas, the schedule date for SEF. The applicant is, therefore, waived from scheduling when at the national territory;
>
> The appointments for the granting and renewing of the residence permit can now be made, at the applicant’s request, for any regional directorate/delegation, allowing therefore to anticipate deadlines;

How the SEF then deals with the process is not stated directly, but Article 51 of
[Regulatory Decree 9/2018, 2018-09-11 - DRE](https://dre.pt/web/guest/home/-/dre/116382281/details/maximized) suggests that permits will be issued as needed.

If the application takes 6-8 months to process, then a residence permit for that period will be issued replacing the D-Visa (including it's conditions)

Comment: But the question is about Portugal.

Comment: @phoog And? Portugal is part of the Schengen Area and thus implements the D-Visa. Until pratical experience from Portugal is reported we will not know if implements in the same way. I don't understand the point of your comment.

Comment: You said it yourself: D visas are country specific.  The fact that Germany and France issue temporary residence permits does not imply that Portugal does.  So this answer isn't particularly informative.  Practical experience is not necessarily the only source of information about the process in Portugal; one might also find out from the Portuguese consulate or the office in Portugal that issues residence permits.

Comment: @phoog the **details** on how it is implemented is country specific. The short term D-Visa is part of the Schengen Code: To enter the Schengen Area and on arrival to start the conversion to residence permit. From **that point on** country specific. Therefore relevant.

Comment: Have you read the Schengen codes?  The type D visa is consistently called a "long term" visa or a "national" visa because it its governed by the national law of the issuing country.  But even if what you say were true, it wouldn't make this answer helpful, because "**that point on**" is the country-specific point this question is about, and the information given in this answer pertains to other countries than the one being asked about.

Comment: @phoog of course I have read it. Just as I have read the implementation instructions, that are publicly available in a language I can read. After the local authority has granted permission, the Cousulate will issue a short term D-Visa so that the person can enter the Schengen Area as an Immigrant. On arrival they report to the local authority which will convert the D-Visa to a residence permit.

Comment: What implementation instructions are you taking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98156/discussion-between-mark-johnson-and-phoog).